# Rename [whiletrue] to [while-loop]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I was surprised to see [whiletrue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whiletrue). It should be renamed to [while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/while-loop) and/or [infinite-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infinite-loop).

Comment: Or perhaps [tag:infinite-loop]

Comment: As a sidenote, you can use this markup `[tag:infinite-loop]`. It's a magic link.

Comment: I did ... why are you telling me? :p (Ninja-edit ftw)

Comment: I disagree with [tag:infinite-loop]. That looks like it might be for discussing bugs that cause unintentional infinite looping, not the `while (true) { ... }` idiom.

Comment: @Kevin my point was more not to blindly go replace it for a while loop, when there might be a case of an infinite loop. That's all. I haven't looked into the content enough to establish it.

Comment: I'd just remove those 50 instances.  The tag is not very useful.  Who is going to follow it, or sift through those 50 instances to see if they missed some profound insight?

Comment: Why does this need to be a tag?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, definitely remove them. There are questions, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874699/efficiency-over-do-whilefalse-block-vs-return) that is tagged [tag:whiletrue] when it is in fact asking about `do {} while (false);` Which is the exact *opposite*.

Comment: There is a difference between [tag:infinite-loop] and [tag:whiletrue] as infinite loop is typically unintentional but someone could intentionally code an 'infinite loop' as while(true) like if you wanted to make a simple server or something like that where you don't have any intention of having a conditional exit apart from just closing the program down.

Comment: The questions tagged [tag:whiletrue] have all been untagged or retagged; the tag is now empty.